# Wrong values - Breaking big char into int Array

Tags: c, arrays, casting, memcpy, atoi

I have a very big string which contains 2 digit numbers and space between them in that order xx xx xx ... etc'.
I'm trying to convert every to digits to int and store in in 20x20 int array.
For this mission I'm using memcpy to coppy the first 2 digit of the string, atoi to cast in to int from char and inner function I wrote which moves the string "left" every for round.
it works fine for something like 60 number and then it gets wrong number to the end of the program.
this is the code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void shiftRightStrign(char * string){

    int i;

    for(i = 0 ; i < 397 ; i++){string[i] = string[i+3];}
}

int main(void){

    char str[3]; 
    char stringArr[] 
    ="08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08 49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00 81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65 52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91 22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80 24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50 32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70 67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21 24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72 21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95 78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92 16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57 86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58 19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40 04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16  07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66 88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69 04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36 20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16 20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54 01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48";                

    int Arr[20][20] = { 0 };
    int num;    
    int liner,row;
    int i,j;


    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        for(j = 0 ; j < 20; j++){
            memcpy(str,stringArr,2);
            Arr[i][j] = atoi(str);
            //printf("atoi value is %d\n",atoi(str));
            if(Arr[i][j] < 9){printf("%d   ",Arr[i][j]);}
            else{printf("%d  ",Arr[i][j]);}
            shiftRightStrign(stringArr);           
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;        
}
```

Comment: When you read a book, do you tear off pages you have read?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that works.

1. I used pointer arithmetic in place of shifting the while character array.
2. I used a specific conversion function as you already know that all your numbers are written using two digits (using a generic function is then not necessary).
3. I corrected your string as there was two spaces between "99 16".
4. I used an appropriate format string in printf to avoid the testing for length of number representation.

Here is what I get:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int convertTwoDigitsToInt(char *p) {
  return (p[0]-'0')*10+p[1]-'0';
}

int main(void){

    char str[3]; 
    char stringArr[] 
    ="08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08 49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00 81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65 52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91 22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80 24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50 32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70 67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21 24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72 21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95 78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92 16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57 86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58 19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40 04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66 88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69 04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36 20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16 20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54 01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48";                

    int Arr[20][20] = { 0 };
    int num;    
    int liner,row;
    int i,j;

    char *current = stringArr;                        // point to the beginning

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        for(j = 0 ; j < 20; j++){
          Arr[i][j] = convertTwoDigitsToInt(current); // convert the two chars pointed
          printf("%2d  ",Arr[i][j]);                  // print the conversion
          current += 3;                               // advance pointer by three places
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;        
}
```

Execution produces:

```
 8   2  22  97  38  15   0  40   0  75   4   5   7  78  52  12  50  77  91   8  
49  49  99  40  17  81  18  57  60  87  17  40  98  43  69  48   4  56  62   0  
81  49  31  73  55  79  14  29  93  71  40  67  53  88  30   3  49  13  36  65  
52  70  95  23   4  60  11  42  69  24  68  56   1  32  56  71  37   2  36  91  
22  31  16  71  51  67  63  89  41  92  36  54  22  40  40  28  66  33  13  80  
24  47  32  60  99   3  45   2  44  75  33  53  78  36  84  20  35  17  12  50  
32  98  81  28  64  23  67  10  26  38  40  67  59  54  70  66  18  38  64  70  
67  26  20  68   2  62  12  20  95  63  94  39  63   8  40  91  66  49  94  21  
24  55  58   5  66  73  99  26  97  17  78  78  96  83  14  88  34  89  63  72  
21  36  23   9  75   0  76  44  20  45  35  14   0  61  33  97  34  31  33  95  
78  17  53  28  22  75  31  67  15  94   3  80   4  62  16  14   9  53  56  92  
16  39   5  42  96  35  31  47  55  58  88  24   0  17  54  24  36  29  85  57  
86  56   0  48  35  71  89   7   5  44  44  37  44  60  21  58  51  54  17  58  
19  80  81  68   5  94  47  69  28  73  92  13  86  52  17  77   4  89  55  40  
 4  52   8  83  97  35  99  16   7  97  57  32  16  26  26  79  33  27  98  66  
88  36  68  87  57  62  20  72   3  46  33  67  46  55  12  32  63  93  53  69  
 4  42  16  73  38  25  39  11  24  94  72  18   8  46  29  32  40  62  76  36  
20  69  36  41  72  30  23  88  34  62  99  69  82  67  59  85  74   4  36  16  
20  73  35  29  78  31  90   1  74  31  49  71  48  86  81  16  23  57   5  54  
 1  70  54  71  83  51  54  69  16  92  33  48  61  43  52   1  89  19  67  48
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using standard [sscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char stringArr[] = "08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08 49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00 81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65 52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91 22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80 24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50 32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70 67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21 24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72 21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95 78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92 16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57 86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58 19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40 04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16  07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66 88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69 04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36 20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16 20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54 01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48";

    int Arr[20][20];
    int i, j;
    size_t strIndex = 0;

    size_t strLength = sizeof(stringArr)-1;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            if (strIndex < strLength)
            {
                sscanf(&stringArr[strIndex], "%02d ", &Arr[i][j]);
                strIndex += 3;

                printf(" %2d", Arr[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
  8  2 22 97 38 15  0 40  0 75  4  5  7 78 52 12 50 77 91  8
 49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48  4 56 62  0
 81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30  3 49 13 36 65
 52 70 95 23  4 60 11 42 69 24 68 56  1 32 56 71 37  2 36 91
 22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
 24 47 32 60 99  3 45  2 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
 32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
 67 26 20 68  2 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63  8 40 91 66 49 94 21
 24 55 58  5 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
 21 36 23  9 75  0 76 44 20 45 35 14  0 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
 78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94  3 80  4 62 16 14  9 53 56 92
 16 39  5 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24  0 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
 86 56  0 48 35 71 89  7  5 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
 19 80 81 68  5 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77  4 89 55 40
  4 52  8 83 97 35 99 16  7 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
 88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72  3 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
  4 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18  8 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
 20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74  4 36 16
 20 73 35 29 78 31 90  1 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57  5 54
  1 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52  1 89 19 67 48
```